# broken image icon in my laravel project

Tags: php, image, laravel-5.4, bootstrap-4

I have an img folder within the public folder of my Laravel 5.4 project.  When I refer to the image with the following code.

```
<img class="mb-3 img-fluid rounded" src="public/img/pdx.jpg" alt="Portland">
```

I get the broken image icon on the page.  I am using Bootstrap 4 cdn for the this page.  What am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just remove public from src attribute and try

Comment: Thanks Amit.  How do vote that you gave the right answer?

Comment: I am adding my solution as an answer you can vote there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove public from src attribute and then try. Because Laravel only understand assets within public folder